# Map function takes non-function as first argument

Tags: haskell

```
-- file: ch19/divby1.hs
divBy :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
divBy numerator = map (numerator `div`)
```

This is the code excerpt from O'reilly - Haskell book.

sample run as,

```
ghci> divBy 50 [1,2,5,8,10]
[50,25,10,6,5]
```

What confuses me is

1. why there are two variables on LHS `divBy` and `numerator` in the expression:

   ```
   divBy numerator = map (numerator `div`)
   ```

What values are the variables `divBy` and `numerator` assigned at the end?

2. `map` function type is
   `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.
   In the above expression, the argument `numerator` is not a function type, and 
   `div` is not of array type. But the code is working!!

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think, you missed the **`** symbol around _div_ inside _map (numerator div)_

Comment: yes, it is the stack.overflow effect.. lemme correct it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### on eta-conversions and signatures

First I think you missed some `` ` ``: in `` numerator `div` ``  (yep I think SO ate them - you have to input this as ``` `` numerator `div` `` ``` to work!)

This:

```
divBy :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
divBy numerator = map (numerator `div`)
```

is another way of writing

```
divBy :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
divBy = \ numerator -> map (numerator `div`)
```

which can be expanded to

```
divBy :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
divBy = \ numerator ns -> map (numerator `div`) ns
```

if you want to can then put the arguments back to the left:

```
divBy :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
divBy numerator ns -> map (numerator `div`) ns
```

and here it might be more clear that `numerator` is the first argument (of type `a`) and `ns` is the second (of type `[a]`) while `divBy` is of course the name of the function.

This works because there is something named [eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) that basically says that you can shorten `\x -> f x` to just `f` - but watch out sometimes you [run into trouble](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) with this but it's often used to write [*point-free-style*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) Haskell code.

### your questions

> What confuses me is
>
> why there are two variables on LHS divBy and numerator in the expression:

```
divBy numerator = map (numerator `div`)
```

**Answer**: those are not *variables* - the first is the name of the function you are declaring in this line and the second is a name for it's first argument.

You might wonder where the second went (see above) - the short answer is: `divBy` is really a function that takes an `a` and returns yet another function `[a] -> [a]` and so there is really only one argument you have to give as long as you return a function (and you do).

> What values, the variables divBy and numerator are assigned at the end?

**Answer**: As I said `divBy` is the name for your function - `numerator` will get the first argument so in

```
 λ> divBy 5 [1..10]
 [5,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

`numerator` is the `5`

> map function type is `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` In the above expression, the argument `numerator` is not a function type, and `div` is not of array type. But the code is working!!
>
> What am i missing here?

Basically you are missing the parentheses - `` (numerator `div`) `` is a so called [*section*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) - it is really the function `` \n -> numerator `div` n `` - think of it as having a *hole* at the second argument of the *infix* `` `div` ``: (disclaimer: pseudocode) `` (numerator `div` _) ``.

So `` (numerator `div`) `` is really a function `Integral a => a -> a` and so it fits the first argument of `map`.

Now where is the second? Well again that is the same story as above: `` map (numerator `div`) `` is a function `Integral a => [a] -> [a]` and that is what was missing for the right side of your declaration `divBy numerator`.

I hope you can figure it out with what I gave you in the first part of this answer.

If you have question leave a comment - I'll try to add explanations where needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would read this code like this:

The type of `divBy` says that it takes two arguments [1], an `a` and an `[a]`, but the LHS of its declaration shows only one argument, namely `numerator`. So let me add the second argument myself, to complete the picture:

`` divBy numerator xs = map (numerator `div`) xs ``

Note that I used the name `xs` (read as x-es as in "more than one x") because the second argument is a list. I could have used, say `x` instead, but using `xs` is a visual reminder that the thing is a list, and it helps a lot in avoiding confusion later.

Now things look a bit clearer:

1. Saying `divBy numerator xs` is exactly the same as saying `` map (numerator `div`) xs `` : Wherever I see the former expression, I can replace it with the latter expression.
2. `` map (numerator `div`) xs `` looks reasonably fine to me: the second argument to `map`, `xs`, is definitely a list, as it should be. The first argument to `map`, `` (numerator `div`) ``, needs to be a function of type `a -> a` where `a` is a type which is an instance of `Integral`. That is, `` (numerator `div`) :: Integral a => a -> a `` must hold. So now I only need to concern myself with why this would be the case.
3. I try to figure out why `` (numerator `div`) `` has type `Integral a => a -> a`. The other answers have explained why this is the case, and I am happy!

[1] To be pedantic, `divBy` only takes one argument etc., but I am now being pedagogic instead.